# Obtain percentage of values in a column

Tags: sql

I have a table called Director, which looks like

```
DirectorID  FirstName   FamilyName          FullName           DoB  Gender
         1     Steven    Spielberg  Steven Spielberg    1946-12-18    Male
         2       Joel         Coen         Joel Coen    1954-11-29    Male
         3      Ethan         Coen        Ethan Coen    1957-09-21    Male
         4     George        Lucas      George Lucas    1944-05-14    Male
         5        Ang          Lee           Ang Lee    1954-10-23    Male
         6     Martin     Scorsese   Martin Scorsese    1942-11-17    Male
         7       Mimi        Leder        Mimi Leder    1952-01-26  Female
```

I am trying to work out the percentage of Female to Male directors

I can work out the number of Male and Female Directors using:

```
SELECT count(*) as myMale from Director 
where Gender = 'Male'
SELECT count(*) as myFemale from Director 
where Gender = 'Female')
```

But I am having trouble combining them to obtain a percentage of Female Directors.

I am looking for the result of 14.3%, which is calculated using:

```
Total Female Directors / (Total Male Directors  + Total Female Directors)
```

or

```
1/(6+1)
```

How would I do this with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method uses aggregation.  Assuming directors are either male or female (binary), then a simple conditional aggregation suffices:

```
select avg(case when gender = 'Female' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_female
from directors;
```

If you want to limit this only to `male` and `female` (assuming other options), then include `where gender in ('female', 'male')`.